# Is it a good approach to handle middleware authentication redirect logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to ask whether this approach of handling Redirects at Middleware level is OK, or how to "make it work in a good manner" because despite the fact that it works in e.g chrome/firefox/postman, then I'm still not sure about it.

---

My Middleware Invoke:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (endpointRequireAuthentication(context.Request.Path))
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Request.Method = "GET";
            context.Request.Path = "/Unauthorized";
        }    
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about this particular example, or about the general idea of handling redirects? I could e.g. offer a better solution for this particular case but that wouldn't necessarily apply for all cases (and vice versa)

Comment: @Flater you can always show both :)

Comment: I'd rather you clarify your question, instead of having to write two separate answers to two possible interpretations of your question.

Comment: Ok, so I think the general way of solving redirects (dependent on User's authentication status (is/isnt)) is the way to go.

Comment: How are you authenticating? Forms, Windows, something else?

Comment: @jwiscarson MVC Webapp with json web token

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should be using something like `IAuthorizationRequirement` to deal with Authorization stuff, which will then generate 401 exception and catch by one on other endpoint or create a custom exception middleware.